# How to count values from one column based on the description in other column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to programming and Python. Lately, I am learning to use pandas.

## What I would like to know

I am wondering what would be the best approach to work only on numbers related to Group II (in the attached DataFrame). I mean e.g. **sum all grades for group II and column 'Project'**. Sure it won't make sense to sum grades, but the data is just for illustration purposes.

I'd be grateful for any advices and suggestions.

## My DataFrame

The code attached will generate random numbers (except for the 'Group' column) but the DataFrame will always be like that:

```
     Name Album  Group  Colloquium_1  Colloquium_2  Project
# 0    B  61738     I             5             4        5
# 1    Z  44071     I             5             5        2
# 2    M  87060     I             5             5        5
# 3    L  67974     I             3             5        3
# 4    Z  15617     I             3             2        3
# 5    Z  91872    II             2             4        5
# 6    H  84685    II             4             2        5
# 7    T  17943    II             2             5        2
# 8    L  54302    II             2             5        3
# 9    O  53433    II             5             4        5
```

## Code to generate my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rd

def gen_num():
    num = ""
    for i in range(5):
        num += str(rd.randint(0,9))
    return num

names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K', 'L','M','N','O', \
             'P','R','S','T','W','Z']

list_names = []
list_album = []
list_group = []
list_coll_1 = []
list_coll_2 = []
list_project = []  

num_of_students = 10

for i in range(num_of_students):
    
    list_names.append(rd.choice(names))
    list_album.append(gen_num())
    list_coll_1.append(rd.randint(2, 5))
    list_coll_2.append(rd.randint(2, 5))
    list_project.append(rd.randint(2, 5)) 
    if i < (num_of_students / 2):
        list_group.append('I')
    else:
        list_group.append('II')
        
group = pd.DataFrame(list_names)
group.set_axis(['Name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
group['Album'] = list_album
group['Group'] = list_group
group['Colloquium_1'] = list_coll_1
group['Colloquium_2'] = list_coll_2
group['Project'] = list_project
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to this is to filter the DataFrame first:

```
group[group["Group"] == "II"]["Project"].sum()
#Out: 18
```

Breaking this up into parts:

First, this part returns a series of bools (True/False) for each row as to whether the values in "Group" are equal to `"II"`:

```
group["Group"] == "II"
#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3    False
#4    False
#5     True
#6     True
#7     True
#8     True
#9     True
#Name: Group, dtype: bool
```

Next, writing this into `group[]` returns a filtered dataframe for those rows that are `True`:

```
group[group["Group"] == "II"]
#  Name  Album Group  Colloquium_1  Colloquium_2  Project
#5    E  77371    II             4             5        3
#6    N  90525    II             4             3        3
#7    H  89889    II             3             4        5
#8    T  88154    II             3             4        5
#9    E  56176    II             3             2        2
```

Using `["Project"]` on the end returns a pandas Series of the values in the column:

```
group[group["Group"] == "II"]["Project"]
#5    3
#6    3
#7    5
#8    5
#9    2
#Name: Project, dtype: int64
```

And lastly `.sum()` returns the sum of the series (18).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DataFrame.groupby` function to analyze data from one or many columns based on "groups" defined in other columns.

For example, something like

```
group.groupby('Group')['Project'].sum()
```

Or,you could use masking if you only want the result:

```
group[group['Group']=='II']['Project'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your only working with 'Group II' data, it may be best to reassign your df to a new variable:

```
df_ii = df[df.Group=='II']
```

Next you could sum the 'Project' grades:

```
df_ii.Project.sum()
```

Or, if summing doesn't make sense, you could take the average:

```
df_ii.Project.mean()
```